# Date format logic

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, date-format, android-calendar

i got this codes for the date format. My examDateFormat is print out like this :

```
Jan   01 = 1
Feb   02 = 11
March 03 = 21
April 04 = 31
```

For example in Feb, it should show 02 but it show 11. I don't know how to fix that logic. Please help me take a look.Thanks!

```
    for (ExamTimetable exam: listOfExam) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
            Date date = null;

            date = format.parse(exam.getM_scheduledDate());
            cal.setTime(date); //correct date
            String examDateFormat = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


            int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            String day = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortWeekdays()[dayOfWeek];

            if (examDateFormat.equals(mDates)) {
                dataList.add(new ExamInfo(exam.getM_subjectFullName(), exam.getM_subjectCode(), examDateFormat + " " + "(" + day + ")", exam.getM_startTime(), exam.getM_endTime(), exam.getM_venueId(), exam.getM_seatingNo()));
            }

        }
```

Comment: put complete code, including print logic. this code is seriously confusing to deduce any thing.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We don't know half of what the values in your code are meant to be. It looks like you're only formatting the date to compare it with another value anyway - why don't you parse the other value? If you *must* format it, why aren't you using `DateFormat` to do so? I'd also strongly recommend using Joda Time or java.time instead of `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Can u show us "exam.getM_scheduledDate()" ?